# Python: problems with read() when it is reading larger data (binary mode)

Tags: python, file-io

This code is working well:

```
f = open("C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/a.txt", "r") 
f.seek(0) 
print f.read(200)
```

But here read() doesn't work properly:

```
print f.read(2000)
```

The output is very short now. Is this a bug? The file contains unicode-data.
Thanks in advance.

Solution:

```
f = open("C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/a.txt", "rb") 
f.seek(0) 
print f.read(200)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your file contains 2000 bytes of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does this produce?

```
import os
filename = "C:/Dokumente und Einstellungen/schnei17/Desktop/a.txt"
print "Filesize: %s" % (os.path.getsize(filename),)
f = open(filename, "r")
data = f.read(2000)
print "Read %s bytes" % (len(data),)
```

> Filesize: 62606 Read 692 bytes

And changing the read mode to binary?

```
import os
filename = "NewProv.txt"
print "Filesize: %s" % (os.path.getsize(filename),)
f = open(filename, "rb")
data = f.read(2000)
print "Read %s bytes" % (len(data),)
```

Comment: Filesize: 62606
Read 692 bytes

Comment: Filesize: 62606
Read 2000 bytes